# Moving VERY old website to New Domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, server-side, opencart2.x

I have been creating a new website for a company and would like some advice on writing a rewrite file.

I obviously would like to keep our current rankings and transfer them to the new site and i am just wanting to make sure I am doing it correctly.

Would a standard 301 redirect with old links to new links work if I also write a rewrite to the home page?

This isn't my area and any help would be great.

Justine

Answer (score 0):

This Redirect htaccess code below in an htaccess file in the old site's folder would redirect all old site pages and posts to identical matching pages and posts with the same identical structure on the new site/domain.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1
```

For some web hosts you need to include the folder name where the website is physically installed. olddomain.com would be the name of the folder and not the URL|URI name.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/olddomain.com$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. IUnfo